# Handling Exception - jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some buttons that `onclick` on them work with two Ajax requests that add and remove products, but this is not of extreme importance in this matter. My problem is this: if the buy button is clicked, the product is added, but if the page is updated it will be there, but I can only have one product the same at a time and if after the updated page the button buy is clicked again, another product is added and this can not happen, because what is already added must be removed from the `removeCartaotoCart` function so that the new one is added so that I have only one product at a time.

What I am not able to do is treat this exception: If the user add a product, refresh the page and he clicks the buy button again, another product is added to the cart, however I can only have one product at a time.

**Button code:**

```
<button style="margin-left: 11%;" type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<button style="display: none; margin-left: 11%;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="Remover" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remover</span></span></button>
```

**Ajax requisition code:**

```
    var productSelected = "";

    function addCartao(product_id){
        if( productSelected != "" ){
            removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
          }
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
        $j.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
          data: {
            product_id: product_id
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache : false,
          beforeSend: function () {

          },
          success: function (retorno) {
            var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);
            productSelected = product_id;   
            $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend'+product_id+'"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
            getSubTotal();
            getGrandTotal();
          },
          complete: function () {

          },
          error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
            window.location.reload();
            history.go(0);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
          }
      });
    }

    function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
        productSelected = ""; 
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
        $j.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
            data:{
                itemId: itemId
            },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(retorno){
                var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);  
                $j('.item-custom #trAppend'+itemId+'').remove();
                getSubTotal();
                getGrandTotal();
            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
            window.location.reload();
            history.go(0);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
          }
        });
    }
```

**Note: I would require that in the update of the page, if there is a product, it is already removed from the cart, and the `removeCartaotoCart` function can be used.**

Comment: Did you write the module behind route `fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao`? If so, or if you have backend knowledge/access to edit, you would have to update its controller to clear the cart before adding a new product. If you can confirm this is the desired effect, I can give you some sample code that would need to be part of the `addCartao` endpoint to clear the cart first.

Comment: @RickBuczynski Yes, that's what you said. And I have also got knowledge / access to the backend to make the necessary edits.

Comment: Ok, answer coming up shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, both which involve a modification to your controller on the backend.

Here's the rough procedure:

1. Remove `removeCartaotoCart` JavaScript function (not needed)
2. Update controller method at endpoint `fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao`
3. Change your AJAX parameter name from `product_id` to `product`

### Option A: Clear Cart Contents on Add to Cart

Edit your controller, so that it looks something like this:

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php';

class Your_Module_AjaxController
    extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    private function _sendResponse(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($product->toJson())
            ->sendResponse();

        exit;
    }

    public function addCartaoAction()
    {
        $cart = $this->_getCart();

        $cart->truncate();

        $product = $this->_initProduct();

        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 1));
        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        $this->_sendResponse($product);
    }
}
```

### Option B: Clear Item in Cart if Exists on Add to Cart

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php';

class Your_Module_AjaxController
    extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    private function _sendResponse(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($product->toJson())
            ->sendResponse();

        exit;
    }

    public function addCartaoAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $quote  = $this->_getQuote(); 

        $product = $this->_initProduct();

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->representProduct($product)) {
                $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
            }
        }

        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 1));
        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        $this->_sendResponse($product);
    }
}
```

#### Option C: Cancel Addition if Exists in Cart

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php';

class Your_Module_AjaxController
    extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    private function _sendResponse(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($product->toJson())
            ->sendResponse();

        exit;
    }

    public function addCartaoAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $quote  = $this->_getQuote(); 

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $canAdd  = true;

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $product->getId()) {
                $canAdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($canAdd) {
            $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 1));
            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            $this->_sendResponse($product);
        } else {
            // Optional error handling sample
            die('{"error":"Product already in cart."}');
        }

    }
}
```

---

Notes:

- I am extending from another controller, this is important.
- You must change your AJAX request parameter from `product_id` to `product`.
- The key to Option A is the call to first `truncate()`
- The key to Option B is the call to `representProduct()`

---

I don't have your controller code so I'm writing my own sample from scratch, but either of these can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: I made the necessary changes, however it only returns me error 500.

Comment: Must be a syntax error in my code, I will test it for myself. Also try to turn on developer mode in `index.php` to see what it tells you.

Comment: If you want or need it, I update the question with my current controller that I use so you can get an idea.

Comment: I just fixed the error, was in the `require_once` statement. See my updated answer.

Comment: It worked out right now. Thank you very much for all your help and attention!

Comment: That's great! You're welcome.

Comment: I will only need to make some changes to your code for particular needs. But anyway, thanks for everything!

Comment: I discovered a small error in your code. I do not know why but the products are not being added to the cart. It appears on the screen as if it had been updated, but if you open a new tab in the browser, the item is not in the cart.

Comment: It is kind of falsely adding the product because when the order is finalized, the product is not as purchased in the order in the backend.

Comment: After the `$cart->addProduct()` call I forgot to add a call to `save()` -- see my updated answer. This is needed to commit changes to the quote.

Comment: It worked, but with another error. The product is being added to the cart, but if there is already any other product added, it removes all that are already in the cart and adds the new one.

Comment: This is why I gave 2 options -- in option A, all items are removed via `$cart->truncate()`; in option B, only the item is removed if it already exists in the cart -- I wasn't clear on your goal so I presented two different solutions. If you can clarify your end goal I might be able to update my answer.

Comment: My final goal would be that every time the user refreshes the page, if there is already a product added through the buttons that I added in the question, they are removed from the cart.

Comment: What I need is something very specific, since only one product of it can be added to the cart. That is why if a product is added by the button and the page is updated and the button is clicked again, new products can be added, which should not happen, since only one product of each can be added per order.

Comment: Ok -- in that case, did "Option B" not work? It was designed to check the cart first for an item of the same, and then it would remove it if there. I will also update my answer with a third option; but that's as far as I can go. Between them you should be able to study the code + core to solve on your own.

Comment: In this case, neither did "Option B" work. The product is added normally, but when the page is updated, it is still in the cart and as I had told you it would need to be removed. I've been on this issue for a few days already and will again study your code. Anyway, thank you for all the help and attention!